# Does the position of heroes in "Empires & Puzzles: RPG Quest" really matters?

Tags: empires-and-puzzles-rpg-quest

I'm playing "Empires & Puzzles: RPG Quest" with other guys and they advised me to place the strongest hero in the center position. I would admit that based on my direct experience with the game, it seems to me that the hero position does not care at all.

Do you know if such assumption is true? Is the position of an hero really meaningful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position on your Defense Team is what's important since when enemies raid your defense runs automatically. Attacks from raiders generate mana for the defending heroes and in general the center position is hit most often.

Because of the number of hits the middle takes, you generally want that hero to be tanky. So if your middle is a healer, then they can heal the damage they can heal a lot of the damage they take. If your middle is a damage dealer, they could be throwing their attack regularly.

A lot of defense teams tend to be based on the nature of the center. For example, a center healer may be flanked by two big damage dealers so any missed shots up the likelihood of dealing big damage. Conversely, if the center is damage, the flanks might be buffs, healing, or riposte (if you are running a fast kill style of defense).

So in short, center is important and your friends are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I always put my strongest defender I the middle (3 position). If the middle falls then your other heros can be doubled up on and then killed faster. The middle position is the spot that takes the most hits because it has 3 facings from which to hit it from. I usually put my weakest hit point defenders on the far flanks ( 1 & 5 positions) because that's the most protected positions in your defensive line. I then put my next strongest heros in the middle positions (2 & 4), so if my middle falls I have a strong back up before they can hit my flanks.

There are tons of strategies about who should be put where. Like a healer middle flanked by two attackers, a three hero middle, etc all that depends upon what heros you have and are available. I had Boril early so he was my anchor middle position for the longest time because of his counter attack capabilities. Eventually he was replaced by Justice because of her higher hit points and thus ability to absorb damage. Whatever strategy you use must be based on what you have available. Just don't let the computer pick it because the computer sets up with what it considers your strongest 5 heros with the strongest in the 1 position and the weakest in the 5 position. Thus zero strategy defensively or offensively.

Comment: thx for the details strategy hindsight

Answer (score 0):

Wing or outside 2 1,5 are for snipers. Hidden away tucked in. Flank. Is for support. Defense buff, 4* healers D Down attack+  tank. Is for the strongest defensive hero ( highest middle number) Healers like Vivica and Kunchen are tank healers. Vivica adds defense buff of 63%  healing 44% I believe. Both are suited for tank position. Both can take a good hit both are slow Mana so takes awhile to charge.